# C#, Windows Forms, LinkLabel Column

Tags: c#, windows, forms, datagridview, linklabel

can anyone provide me with a working example of creating a custom datagridview column control with a linklabel inside?
First of all, I can't use LinkColumn, as I need to have multiple, clickable links in the same cell. Examples found all over the Internet (and trust me, I've been searching for hours) don't exactly help because of my lack of knowledge.
I need to achieve something like in this mockup:

```
| People   | Files            |
|----------|------------------|
| Person A | File 1, File 2   |
| Person B | File 1           |
```

Where File 1, File 2 for Person A and File 1 for Person B all are distinct URLs and there's no need for custom text, just "File 1", "File 2", etc.  An ideal situation would be if my custom cell could be databound with a parameter in the likes of List<\string> UrlList, where elements of that list would be the URLs pointing to the download location for that files, which would launch in a browser window when clicking on the suitable file. 
Can anyone help me with that or just point me somewhere closer than the calendar column examples, provided by Microsoft?

Comment: I don't want to. I just need some general directions on what to do as I haven't got any idea how to approach this problem. I know I need to create a custom cell/column hosting - what's best - my own usercontrol. But there are basically no examples on how to do that efficiently - the only sample I've been able to locate is not even avaiable for download from Microsoft's site. The other custom cells are always derived from the textboxcell control and I'm not sure that's what I need.

Comment: y dont u put them in different columns? or use a combo box? even if put it in a text columns, there is no way to know which text u clicked.

Comment: That's why I'm leaning towards the linklabel control - it can be used to host distinct links under one label. Different columns won't be much use here, as the bound datatable is generated programatically and I don't know what the number of maximum possible links will be.

Answer (score 0):

You could have two different datagrids

When you select one row just fill the other datagrid with all the files

On the Cell Click Event just get the values from your people column and fill in the other  grid with the associated files.

You can get the value using this 
`DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value`

When you Click on the Cell with the file that you want you can open it up with something like this.

```
String webAddress = "http://www.google.com/"
Process.Start(webAddress)
```